# How can i avoid duplicate values when inserting to the database

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know this question has being asked already but i also need to learn. I want to check for Id number when you doing registration but am not sure on how i can do it. for now i am adding validations but everything works on Save.

Here  is what i have so far but i don't have an idea on how i can pass Id number field to check if it does exist. your guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

my code:

```
     public async Task<bool> AddFleet(FleetModel fleet)
     {
        bool IsDone = false;
        try
        {
            using (SidDbContext db = new SidDbContext())
            {
                FleetVehicle fv = new FleetVehicle()
                {
                    BranchId = fleet.BranchId,
                    Description = fleet.Description,
                    Registration = fleet.Registration

                };
                db.FleetVehicle.Add(fv);
                db.SaveChanges();

                Fleet _fleet = new Fleet
                {
                    FitmentTeamId = Convert.ToInt32(fleet.FitmentTeamId),
                    Capacity = fleet.Capacity,
                    BranchId = fleet.BranchId,
                    Active = true                     
                };
               var results = db.Fleet.Add(_fleet);
                db.SaveChanges();

                db.FleetVehicleLink.Add(new FleetVehicleLink { FleetId = _fleet.Id ,FleetVehicleId = fv .Id});
                db.SaveChanges();
                //add team

                foreach (var u in fleet.TeamMember1)
                {
                    db.FitmentUsersLink.Add(new FitmentUsersLink { FitmentTeamId = _fleet.Id, UsersId = u });                       
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                IsDone = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return IsDone = true;
    }


function RegistrationFunction() {
try {

    $.support.cors = true;
    var registration = {
        Idnumber: $('#txtIdnumber').val(),
    }
```

Js code:

```
    $.ajax({

        url: BaseUrl + "Registrations/RegistrationMethod",
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        registration: registration,

        if(registration)
        {
            var form = $(this)
            swal({

                title: "Oops! Duplicate Student ID Number......",
                text: "ID Number "+ $('#txtIdnumber').val()+ " already being used",
                Idnumber: $('#txtIdnumber').val(),
                type: "Warning",
                showCancelButton: true                
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: If, like in this case, only one can exist then just use the primary key as the ID number. You won't get duplicates that way. but more importantly, good design goes a long way. Don't allow unique numbers to be "assigned" by the user - let the system handle it.

Comment: I get what you saying, but in this case Id number is just a normal fields like others..i don't want to use it as a primary key. I just want to validate the Id number using ajax and other fields i will handle them on UI

Comment: Use the `UNIQUE` constraint on the column within the database then attempt to insert. if it fails, handle the resulting exception, otherwise your record goes in.

Comment: Can you post your MVC code?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend @Takarii 's comment. I don't think you should use exceptions to handle the executing flow of the application... Seems dirty. Auto generate the student id, Either a GUID or a auto generated column.